# How to read SVN Tortoise Command from Java application

Tags: java, svn

As I am doing an application which requires to do all the operations like checkout, checkin, commit, rollback and etc.. Please can any one give command line options for SVN tortoise?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, you want to implement a Java application that calls Subversion commands. I think there are 3 options you could go with:

1. (and best one): Use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) as a pure Java implementation of the Subversion API in Java. So you have there Java classes and methods and can do anything you want (if you understand how to use it correctly).
2. You could use [JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL) which is more difficult to install, but then comparable in usage to SVNKit. However, the implementation differs on different platforms (no Java-only implementation), so depending on your usage scenario, it may not be an option.
3. You could just start svn commands from Java, but I would not do that.

There is enough information available on the internet how to do the base commands with SVNKit, so just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is a front end to subversion. See the [Version Control with
Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) book for a list of all the command line commands. [Appendix E. Command Line Interface Cross Reference](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html) of the TortoiseSVN documentation provides another source for the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You will get enough help from internet about [tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html).

You can create a repository in system folder or in Eclipse.

These steps will install SVN plug-in in Eclipse.

Open Eclipse.
Go to Help  Click Install New Software
Click “Add” button
Put “Subclipse 1.2.x (Eclipse 3.2+)” under Name and “http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x” under Location:
Click ok
Select subclipse selection option in selection window.  Select all
Click next button   n/a
In review the items to be installed window. Click next.
Licenses must be reviewed and accepted before the software can be installed. Click I accept radio box.  Click finish.
During installation eclipse may ask for the validity of plugin being installed. Click ok
After installation. Restart Eclipse.

Create SVN Repository Location in Eclipse

In the navigator perspective, right click and choose new
Choose SVN > Checkout Projects from SVN
Select the option to create a new repository location.
Fill in the location of the SVN repository (https://link-to-repository) and click next. Project info is loaded.
It may ask username and password or validation of repository site certificates. Click “accept permanently”.
From RAD File menu, choose Import to display the import manager. Choose Checkout Projects from SVN. Click Next
Select Use existing repository location option to enable the Next button.
It will load all projects from repository in “trunk”.   Expand trunk menu option
Select all the projects one by one to import in projects in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not call svn commands directly from java? I mean can't we open a command prompt using a RunTime instance and passing the svn command to it.Is that a bad idea?If yes, what are the disadvantages?